# ¿Cómo puedo generar un numero aleatorio entre 100 y -100?

Tags: c++, random

Estoy haciendo un programa sobre montículos en el cual tengo un fichero de jugadores con sus puntuaciones que vuelco en un montículo. Cada elemento es un pair de un int y string, es decir: pair<int,string>. El entero sería la puntuación y el string el nombre del usuario. Ahora lo que quiero hacer es generar un número aleatorio entre 100 y -100 (por debajo de 0) para sumar o restar a la puntuación que tiene el jugador. He probado con estas lineas del srand pero no se si funciona así exactamente:

```
srand(1);

actualizacion = rand()%(100-(-100));
```

Me gustaría saber es así o no, gracias.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y esto seria en que lenguaje? falta esa etiqueta....

Comment: Hola Rafa, podrias decir si la respuesta dada te fue util, gracias

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

srand(time(NULL));
actualizacion = rand() % 200 - 100;
```

Primero se hace uso del **procedimiento srand** para inicializar el generador de números aleatorios, creando de esta forma lo que se conoce como "semilla".

Posteriormente se genera un número aleatorio entre **0** y **200**, a este número se le restará **100** para obtener el número aleatorio en el rango deseado de **0** a **100**.

**Ejemplos:**

Si el número aleatorio obtenido es **199** al restar **100** obtenemos **99**.

Si el número aleatorio obtenido es **1** al restar **100** obtenemos **-99**.